# Adding Items in ListView From Firebase in Android Studio

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In android I am simply add some values in listview from firebase now I data pair like:

[image]

I am using array list for adding this items on my adapter by the help of ChildEventListener, Here is my class :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {


ListView listView;
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>(10);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);


    final Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://f.......firebaseio.com/");

    myFirebaseRef.child("Donors").child("Baldia Town").child("Ittehad Town").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getKey() + " was " + dataSnapshot.getValue());
            Log.d("obj", dataSnapshot.getKey() + " , " + dataSnapshot.getValue());

            arr.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDonnors);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,arr);
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    TextView text = (TextView) view;
    Toast.makeText(this, text.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Note: by this I simply get the Log :
Faizan: 2341
Hussain: 1345
Khezar: 2233
Zeeshan: 1122

but I want to add the name only in "arr" (list) . and when user press "zeeshan" I simply get its id (datasnapshot.getValue)like 1122 in any variable.
Can anyone help me to do this??

Comment: While a picture may be worth a thousand worth, the same doesn't apply when it's a picture of text. Please replace the image with the actual JSON, which you can easily export from your Firebase dashboard.